# So how did a closed question come back to life?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15292/pulling-my-hair-out-over-a-4-bit-architecture-there-ought-to-be-some-law-here-s) hot mess of a question — unclear and rambling — got [closed](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/15292/timeline#history_efa84cc4-0177-4ddb-ae96-fb3fc5f851b7), but then got reopened despite a [3:2 vote](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/15292/timeline#review_10847) against reopening. How, and why?

Comment: I was wondering myself. While I enjoyed pointing out some of the ways, it is a generic CPU design question and not really RC.SE material, so I didn't mind it being closed wile I was writing my answer- and quite surprised by seeing it again without being marked as such. (BTW: interesting link. didn't know about the timeline before :)

Comment: After the review, three other people voted to open it.

Comment: Aaaand it's at 3 votes for re-closing.  (I'm one of the re-closers.  The question really does ramble and needs focus.)  Like Raffzahn, I wrote an answer, didn't mind it closing, and hadn't seen that format of the timeline before.

Comment: ...and it's closed. The "timeline" view is accessed by clicking on the icon that looks sort of like a clock, below the voting arrows for each question and answer. The timeline feature has been around for a while, but I think the icon to access it quickly is new.

Comment: yes, I link to the timeline in my post

Answer (score 9):

**Because 5 users voted to reopen, but...**

So, there are 2 mechanics happening here:

1. Votes from outside the review queue are not listed inside the review
2. "Leaving close" the question doesn't invalidate existing reopen votes

As far as the [public timeline](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/15292/timeline?filter=NoVoteDetail#history_197e13ab-f8eb-41fd-9805-80fe1d521c03) states:

1. RichF and JeremyP cast the reopen votes directly from the question
2. Michael and peterh voted to reopen from [the review](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/10847)
3. The review ended with "leave closed" and the question currently had 4 reopen votes
4. Brian cast the final reopen vote directly from the question, reopening the question